# PyDev-Eclipse Python not configured

Tags: python, windows, eclipse

After forced restart due to frozen laptop (windows 7 pro, 32 bit) Eclipse is providing the following message:

> It seems that the Python interpreter is not currently configured.
>
> How do you want to proceed?"

Clicking the Auto config option and then ok I get the Python Interpreters window with the right name (Python), Location (`c:\Program Files\Python27\python.exe`) and system libs.

It all looks ok but clicking OK or Apply doesn't seem to do anything and the whole thing starts from the beginning (the message about Python not currently configured...).

I've checked my `.pydevproject` permissions and I have full control over the file.
I also have dropbox sync-ing the project files but it has been ok for a while now.

What is wrong, what should I check/do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the log files under workspace/.metadata shows exception wwith the following message:
!MESSAGE For input string: "0 (xxxx xxxxx's conflicted copy 2013-08-16)"

These are files created by dropbox due to conflicts. Eclipse was not expecting these sort of files and when trying to read them raised and exception.

Deleting all such files restored Eclipse's configuration.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if it is global or local (project-related).

- Globally you can set the interpreter via the path 
  `Window`-Menu → `Preferences` → `PyDev` → `Interpreter - Python`.
- Project-related this can be done via 
  `right-click on project` → `Properties` → `PyDev - Interpreter/Grammar`.

Have a look at both and make sure that both are set to correct values.

Comment: Thanks Alfe. The local Interpreter/Grammar window says: "Please configure an interpreter in the related preference before proceeding". The problem described in my question happens when I try to set the interpreter in the global setting (Window->preference->PyDev->Interpreter-Python). Do you know where (what file) these preferences stored?